# Python Calculate Monthly Averages Iterating through multiple years

Tags: python, arcgis

Morning.

I'm currently having to average data sets to monthly averages; some data sets are bi-monthly, weekly, and some daily.

I've got my base code:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

arcpy.env.workspace="F:\\Converted_GIMMS3G" #change to folder with year of interest
print "Boots n Pants"


for n in range (1,10):
    m=str(n)

    rasters=arcpy.ListRasters("Rotategeo02_"+m+"*", "tif")#change year of tiffs you want to find
    print "boots"
    output = "F:\\Converted_GIMMS3G\\TEST\\Month_"+m+"_2002.tif" #change folder year and output year

for raster in rasters:
# Process: Cell Statistics
    print (rasters)
    arcpy.gp.CellStatistics_sa(rasters, output, "MEAN", "DATA")


for z in range (10,13):

    rasters2=arcpy.ListRasters("Rotategeo02_"+str(z)+"*", "tif")#change year of tiffs you want to find
    print "pants"
    output = "F:\\Converted_GIMMS3G\\TEST\\Month_"+str(z)+"_2002.tif" #change folder year and output year

    for item in rasters2:
        print(rasters2)
        arcpy.gp.CellStatistics_sa(rasters2, output, "MEAN", "DATA")
```

Currently this: "Rotategeo02_"+str(z)+"*" only goes one year per run. 
What I would like it to do is: I'd like to make it iterate through years so, 2000 - 2014. I've tried tweaking it myself only to get a bunch of errors. Wondering if anyone can provide thoughts or inputs to this.

Using 2.7 version of Python for scripting.

I've tried this:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

arcpy.env.workspace="F:\\Converted_GIMMS3G" #change to folder with year of interest
print "Boots n Pants"
fdata = "78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 00, 01, 02 , 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13"
fdata = fdata.split(",")

for n in range (1,10):
    for line in fdata:
        m=str(n)
        rasters=arcpy.ListRasters("Rotategeo"+fdata+"_"+m+"*", "tif")#change year of tiffs you want to find
        print "boots"
        output = "F:\\Converted_GIMMS3G\\Month_"+m+fdata+".tif" #change folder year and output year

    for raster in rasters:
# Process: Cell Statistics
        print (rasters)
        arcpy.gp.CellStatistics_sa(rasters, output, "MEAN", "DATA")


for z in range (10,13):
    for line in fdata: 
        rasters2=arcpy.ListRasters("Rotategeo"+fdata+"_"+str(z)+"*", "tif")#change year of tiffs you want to find
        print "pants"
        output= "F:\\Converted_GIMMS3G\\Month_"+str(z)+fdata+".tif" #change folder year and output year

    for item in rasters2:
        print(rasters2)
        arcpy.gp.CellStatistics_sa(rasters2, output, "MEAN", "DATA")
```

When doing so, I get this error: File "H:/Sarah_Smith/IDS_data/ECV_SOILMOISTURE_MERGED/ECV_SOILMOISTURE_SSMV_MERGED/monthly average_GIMMS.py", line 24, in 
    rasters=arcpy.ListRasters("Rotategeo"+fdata+"_"+m+"*", "tif")#change year of tiffs you want to find
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: *"I've tried tweaking it myself only to get a bunch of errors."* - what have you tried, and precisely what went wrong? *"Using newest version of Python for scripting."* - at least specify 2.x or 3.x.

Comment: Hi Jon, I've tried making an FData list of the years [fdata = (00,01,etc...) and inserting that into the code and I would get cannot concate str and list.

Comment: If you are using python 3 then  printing without parens will cause an error so `print "pants"` etc.. is not valid syntax, it should be `print("pants")`

Comment: Using 2.7 (sorry for confusion before the edit, looked at the wrong folder... too many programs on one machine) Usually work installs the newest version of the software on my computer but I might be mistaken this time.

Comment: The code I showed above runs just peachy, I'd just like it to run multiple years instead of one so the print "pants" works. (I may like that pig commercial too much re: the boots n pants... LOL)

Comment: @Sesmith926 please edit the question to include [a minimal example](http://sscce.org) of the failing code and the full error traceback.

Comment: I presumed when I read "Using newest version of Python for scripting" you meant you were using python 3.4.

Comment: Will do jon. Editing now. Done.

Comment: `fdata` is a list, I think you mean `"Rotategeo"+line+...` `fdata = fdata.split(",")` creates a list

Comment: Padric, thanks! That gets it to run... now I just need it to read the files; I believe I have an error in my format of the file names.

Comment: Also, odd question but I've always wondered, does the order of the numbers in the Fdata line matter? Should 00 be first, or is it ok where it's at?

Comment: I doubt it would  matter but `sorted(fdata)` will put the values in ascending order. What is `output` supposed to do?

Comment: Output just writes the new file to that location.